# Create a new Event in Google Calendar using a Post Request

Tags: java, post, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to create a new event in Google Calendar using a POST Request but I always get a 400 error.

So far I have this:

```
String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/"+ calendarID + "/events?access_token=" + token;
String data = "{\n-\"end\":{\n\"dateTime\": \"" + day + "T" + end +":00.000Z\"\n},\n" +
                        "-\"start\": {\n \"dateTime\": \"" + day + "T" + begin + ":00.000Z\"\n},\n" +
                        "\"description\": \"" + description + "\",\n" +
                        "\"location\": \"" + location + "\",\n" +
                        "\"summary\": \"" + title +"\"\n}";



System.out.println(data);

URL u = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();           
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
String a = connection.getRequestMethod();
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth" + token); 
connection.setUseCaches(false);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes(data);
wr.flush();

// Get the response
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String line;
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
   System.out.println(line);
}
wr.close();
rd.close();
```

But when I create the BufferedReader to read my response I get a 400 error. What's wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Google APIs Client Library for Java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/)? It will make operations like this much simpler. Once you've configured the client library and created a service object, it's relatively easy to make API calls. This example creates and inserts an event into a calendar:

```
Event event = new Event();

event.setSummary("Appointment");
event.setLocation("Somewhere");

ArrayList<EventAttendee> attendees = new ArrayList<EventAttendee>();
attendees.add(new EventAttendee().setEmail("attendeeEmail"));
// ...
event.setAttendees(attendees);

Date startDate = new Date();
Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 3600000);
DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));
DateTime end = new DateTime(endDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));

Event createdEvent = service.events().insert("primary", event).execute();

System.out.println(createdEvent.getId());
```

It assumes you have created a service object as outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't use the Google APis since I'm using GWT and it says that is not compatible with it. I've found what my error was. I had 2 "-" signals in the data String that wasn't supposed to be there.